# Column space of a $QR$-factorization

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let A be an $m$ x $n$ matrix with linearly independent columns and let $A=QR$ be a $QR$-factorization of $A$. Show that $A$ and $Q$ have the same column space.

I honestly don't have a clue where to start. How could I show that 2 matrices have the same column space at all? Could anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let A be an $m$ x $n$ matrix with linearly independent columns and let $A=QR$ be a $QR$-factorization of $A$. We want to show that  $A$ and $Q$ have the same column space.

Suppose that A = QR where R is an nxn upper triangular matrix. This is always possible as we partition A = QR = $\begin{bmatrix}R_1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. This is sometimes called the thin QR factorization or reduced QR factorization. See [*Wiki QR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) as this is needed given that we are not starting from the typical $nxn$ case (tridiagonal matrix).

Given a matrix $B$, $y \in col(B)$ if and only there is an $x$ such that $Bx = y$.

Lets suppose that $y \in col(A)$. Then there is an $x$ such that $Ax = y$, and we can
rewrite this equation as $Q(R_1x) = y$. Let w = $R_1x$, which is a vector. Then w has the property that $Qw = y$, so $y \in col(Q)$. We can conclude that $Col(A) \subseteq Col(Q)$.

Next, suppose that $y \in col(Q)$. Then there is an $x$ such that $Qx = y$. Of course $Q = AR_1^{-1}$, so we can rewrite this as $AR_1^{-1}x = y$. Again, lets write this vector as $w = R_1^{-1}x$. Thus $w$ has the property that $Aw = y$, thus $y \in col(A)$. We conclude that $Col(Q) \subseteq Col(A)$.

Because we proved the opposite inclusion above, it must be the case that $Col(A) = Col(Q)$.

Comment: You are very welcome and I hope it is clear! Regards

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me! ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you - maybe another slow night!

Comment: Maybe, indeed. I'm going to have to take a break and head to the pharmacy before it closes...maybe it will "pick up" the moment I leave to do that!

Comment: I guess there is a Q before the matrix [R1; 0]'